# Error of AVD in Android Studio in Fedora 27

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed Android Studio in Fedora, but I get an error when I try to install AVD:

**See Below Image :**

[image]

Comment: Does your HDD have enough free storage?

Comment: hi i do this https://bytefreaks.net/applications/android-studio-no-space-left-on-device  and it's  work